# Error received while accessing restdb.io API using Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, firefox

I have the following issue using [restdb.io](https://restdb.io/) and Firefox:

The following code returns an error when using Firefox (44.x and 45.0)

```
function getData(){
   var jqhxr = $.ajax({
                           type: 'GET',
                            url: 'https://<-my REST endpoint->',
                        "async": true,
                  "crossDomain": true,
                       dataType: 'json',
                      "headers": {
                                  "x-apikey": "<-my API key->",
                                  "content-type": "application/json" }
                       }).done(function() {
                           console.log('success');
                       }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                           console.log('request failed jqXHR: ' +  JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                           console.log('request failed: ' +  textStatus);
                       }).always(function() {
                           console.log('complete');
                   });
          }
```

JSON payload received is:

```
request failed jqXHR: {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}
```

But the same code runs OK using Chrome (48.0.2564.116 m) and IExplorer (11.0.9600.17420).

Any idea why this restDB.io/Firefox issue arises or how can I workaround it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with version 43 Firefox included a change to reject new security certificates made using an old algorithm called "SHA-1".

This issue occurs because a third-party application you are using intercepts secure connections made by your browser.

This article explains how to see if this problem affects you and, if so, how to resolve it:

[mozill support - Unable to access secure (HTTPS) sites in Firefox 43](http://mzl.la/1J2O6PS)

The best way to fix this problem is to install the latest version of Firefox from the Firefox download page, which has a fix for this problem. You will need to download and run the Firefox installer manually, using an unaffected copy of Firefox or another browser.